# ¿Cómo enviar correos electronicos con acentos?

Tags: c#

Quiero que en el contenido del correo que se genera con c# envíe el mensaje con acentos ya logré que se hiciera en el asunto pero en el cuerpo o contenido del correo no, manda un mensaje sin sentido

```
correos.To.Clear();
correos.Body = "";
correos.Subject = "=?ISO-8859-1?B?" + 
               Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(asunto)) + "=?=";
correos.Body =mensaje; 
correos.Subject = asunto;
correos.IsBodyHtml = true;
correos.To.Add(destinatario.Trim());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes que usar la propiedad [`BodyEncoding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.bodyencoding(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
correos.BodyEncoding =  System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

Igualmente, para el asunto puedes usar [`SubjectEncoding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.subjectencoding(v=vs.110).aspx) en lugar de lo que estás haciendo:

```
correos.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda es lo que me hacia falta.